# Relation between Upthrust and Newtons Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Using Newton's $2nd$ law of motion, show that when an object floats on the surface of water, the upthrust experienced by the object and the weight of object must be equal?

The first thing is I don't understand the whole question and the second thing is that I have a doubt that the floating object has acceleration or not??
So please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, you need to prove that for floating bodies Buoyant force is equal to weight of the object.

Just draw the Free Body Diagram of the object.

*Since the object has no acceleration, so Buoyant Force=Weight of the object.*

[image]

Image source:http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/104_2012_web_projects/Daniela_Wilner/Images/Plastic_Cube.jpg